# Eclipse project can't find "org.joda"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jodatime

I'm using Eclipse Kepler, and Apache Maven 3.1.1. I just installed both and did so properly as far as I know.

I'm trying to install Joda Time from the Maven repository. I added the dependencies to the pom.xml, but my project can't resolve the joda libraries even with a maven clean install.

My repository is located at USER_FOLDER/.m2/repository/. The joda-time folder and its contents are present there after I navigate to my project folder in a prompt and run "mvn clean", then "mvn install".

I haven't changed any build paths or other project settings in my Eclipse project.

Eclipse Maven integration is installed.

I followed this tutorial found on the Spring website: http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

**My file structure is as follows:**

```
USER
|____ .m2
|    |____ repository
|         |____ joda-time [and other folders such as org]
|              |____ joda-time
|                   |____ 2.3
|                        |____ _remote.repositories
|                        |____ joda-time-2.3.jar
|                        |____ joda-time-2.3.jar.sha1
|                        |____ joda-time-2.3.pom
|                        |____ joda-time-2.3.pom.sha1
|____ workspace
|    |____ hello
|    |    |____ [project files]
|    |    |____ pom.xml
|    |    |____ dependency-reduced-pom.xml
|    |    |____ target
|    |         |____ [compiled files. Nothing related to Joda, though]
|    |____ .metadata [with .plugins folder and others]
```

**Here is my pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main.java.hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Here is my HelloWorld.java main file.** On the import line, I get the error message "The import org.joda cannot be resolved".

```
package main.java.hello;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your Eclipse project is actually using m2e? Right-click on the project and see whether it has a `Maven >` submenu or an option to "add Maven nature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Is also required to generate project files which includes .classpath for eclipse.

Comment: This is not required if the OP is using m2eclipse, which he indicates he is.

Comment: This is what I was missing I think! However, now I'm getting the error "Error: Could not find or load main class main.java.hello.HelloWorld" when I try to run the project. This happens whether I set in my pom file the mainClass to be "hello.HelloWorld" or "main.java.hello.HelloWorld".

@chrylis. I went to Help >> Install New Software, and used the link "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" for the path. I tried to install the plugins that were listed, but that were already installed with the Kepler download.

Comment: You have Kepler, why not go into eclipse marketplace. This is under help option by the name of eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the project and click on Configure> Convert Project to Maven Project

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try.

Are there any Maven errors whatsoever listed in the 'Markers' View?  (Other than the missing import, of course).  Frequently, a misspelled Maven configuration can be the cause of this problem.

If not, try one of the following:

1. Right-click the project and select Maven->Update Project.
2. Restart Eclipse.
3. Delete the errors, quit, and run "mvn clean compile" from the command line.  Start Eclipse, right click your project, and "Refresh".
4. Delete the errors, quit, delete everything in your m2 repository, and run "mvn clean compile" from the command line.  tart Eclipse, right click your project, and "Refresh"
5. Sacrifice 50 bulls to Lord Eclipse.  Sometimes this is the only resort.  I don't like it, but the alternative is to shell out bucks for Intellij.

Comment: Does it mean anything if I right click on the project and I DON'T see any mention of Maven?

Comment: You need to add Maven nature to your project.  Right click your project, select Configure->Convert to Maven Project